# How to do "erasStakers" in Rust?

Tags: polkadot-js, subxt, substrate-archive

*Very sorry for such a newbie question; just don't know where else to ask*

Essentially, I want to programmatically dump from the network who won the most recent election. To do so, I'm issuing an `erasStakers(...)`[https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#erasstakersu32-accountid32-palletstakingexposure] RPC call. So far as I understand it, there is no direct RPC API call for `erasStakers(...)`, and one needs to interact with the node through `getStorage(...)` to learn the election result.

Yet the Polkadot Explorer somehow shows the human-readable output:
[image: Polkadot Explorer with an election winners shown]

However, when I do in my Nodejs code:

```
await api.query.staking.erasStakers(635, null)
// => {"total":0,"own":0,"others":[]}
```

It seems the Polkadot Node just returns an empty object.

I also know about Parity's `substrate-debug-kit`[https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-debug-kit/blob/master/offline-election/src/subcommands/staking.rs] repo, which queries the Polkadot's node. I believe I could leverage `sub_storage::read` from that repo, but I can't guess the correct "Prefix" parameter and the return type to get `erasStakers`; it just says "get_pairs failed", whatever I try.

**Is there a way to get either in my NodeJS or in my Rust code something akin to what I see in the picture — a human readable structure representing an `erasStakers(...)` call?**

*I'm new to Polkadot, so apologies if I mixed up terms, or misunderstood something trivial — any help would be much appreciated.*

Comment: This is not correct `await api.query.staking.erasStakers(635, null)` - use `.entries`, see https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/storage#how-do-i-use-entrieskeys-on-double-maps (that is what the apps UI uses above)

Comment: You don't need a specific RPC call, what the UI is doing is querying the storage directly which is done with `state_getStorage`, but it requires to pass the storage key encoded which is not friendly to do by hand but your Rust client should be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment above, to iterate over a map, you need to use the [entries methods](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries), for double maps there is also a [cookbook example](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/storage/#how-do-i-use-entrieskeys-on-double-maps).

In the case of `api.query.staking.erasStakers(...)` it returns a specific entry, and only the value. In the case of `api.query.staking.erasStakers.entries(...)` it returns the full map, will all keys & values for each entry.

(This is obviously a much heavier operation, apart from the fact that the return type is different, since it needs to chunk the values and iterate on the Node RPC side)